# How do I use multiple functions correctly? I’m getting a “too many arguments message”

Tags: excel

This is the formula I am using:

=IF(AC<C, “PD”, “C”, IF(isblank(AC, “C”)))

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

IF has 3 parameters:

1. boolean statement
2. what if 1. is true
3. what if 1. is false

if 1. then 2. else 3.

Excel does separate parameters using ; and not ,
so your if sould be:

=IF(AC<C; "PD"; IF(AC="";"C";AC))

Even if I don't understand what is AC and what is C, I assume this is a sample.

Comment: `Excel does separate parameters using ; and not , so your if sould be:` this is not a true statement.  whether one uses `;` or `,` depends on their local settings.  And it has been decided that we would use EN-US settings in answers.  Your formula should be using the `,` to meet that criteria.